# Visual Studio - complete key sequence with shortcut or text

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way I can complete text in the editor with Visual Studio? It would be great if there was a keyboard shortcut or a key sequence that would autopopulate a longer sequence. For exmaple, I can never remember `from remote_pdb import RemotePdb; RemotePdb('x.y.z.q', 1234).set_trace()` and I always have to search for it, then copy it where I need to set a break point. I would love being able to type something like `brkpt` and have visual-studio auto-complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a snippet to do this for you.

How to use? You gave your snippet a name (`mySnippet`, for example). Every time you type this name in your code, you have an option, like a function, to use this snippet. Then, this name is substituted by your code, like in your example. Follow my example below of one snippet that I use.

In Visual Studio Code: File > Preferences > User Snippets > Select a type for your snippet (php.json in my example). Content of the file:

```
"showErrors": {
    "prefix": "_showErrors",
    "body": [
        "ini_set('display_errors', 1);",
        "ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);",
        "error_reporting(E_ALL);"
    ],
    "description": "Insert an script to show php errors."
}
```

- The first line is the name of my snippet.
- The prefix is what VSCode will identify when you type this name.
- The body is the statements that will be included in your code.
- The description is just something to tell other users about what your code does.